# Multiprocessing vs Multithreading for making multi-client server applications

Tags: multithreading, sockets, server, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am creating a real-time server to handle many parallel request from clients.I have read articles about multi-threading and multiprocessing with their own pros and cons but I am confused what should i use.

my server will accept request from client, parse its request header and do database query and such stuffs afterwards.

So should I use multiprocessing, where I create new process to handle each client request or just threads would be fine.

Also their can be possibility of heavy traffic.

Comment: new processes are much heavier than threads, so if handling client request takes very short time and does not require a lot of memory (as in most www servers), spawning processes is too much overhead and threads are better solution. You may also take look into coroutines, which often are good solution. If you serve small number of heavy tasks, you may opt for processes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but i am making a connection with client which will persist till any network loss, also client can send messege anytime and also server can send messege ( bidirectional) in simple words i am trying to achive something like whatsapp server? Now can you recommend process vs threads in this case??

Comment: if there is few clients, process could be an option, they are better isolated so may have some security advantages, but with proper data segregation threads also are on the table. Threads also may be long lived (and because small footprint may be better). And with proper data model coroutines also should suffice.